# If $\lim f(x) = L > 0$ and $\lim g(x) = \infty$, show that $\lim f(x) g(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Suppose that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L > 0$, and $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = \infty$. Show that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) g(x) = \infty$. If $L = 0$, show by example that this conclusion may fail.

Suppose that

$$f(x) = 1/x^2, \lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$$
$$g(x) = x, \lim_{x\to c} g(x) = \infty$$

In this example, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) g(x) = 0$ as c approaches infinity. If the example is tweaked a little bit, this no longer holds.

$$f(x) = 1/x, \lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0$$
$$g(x) = x^2, \lim_{x\to c} g(x) = \infty$$

Now $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) g(x) = \infty$ and it didn't matter that the limit of $f(x)$ is 0.

What is happening to the $\delta$-neighborhood? When there is just $f(x)$, then the interval for the neighborhood is $[c-\delta, c+\delta]$.

When $f(x) \cdot g(x)$, because the limit of $g(x)$ is larger than the limit of $f(x)$, will the  $\delta$-neighborhood have a larger interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $c$ to be a real number, fix $M>0$ arbitrarily. To show that $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty$$
we need to show that $\exists\delta>0$ such that $f(x)g(x)>M\ \ \forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

Now, by definition of limit of $f$ at $c$, we have that $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that $f(x)>\dfrac L2\ \ \forall x\in(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$.

Also, by definition of limit of $g$ at $c$, we have that $\exists\delta_2>0$ such that $g(x)>\dfrac {2M}L\ \ \forall x\in(c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2)$

Taking $\delta$ to be the minimum of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, we have $f(x)g(x)>M \ \ \forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ and we are done.

Comment: Why does this argument fall apart when L = 0? You can't say $g(x) > \frac{2M}{L}$ because that would be undefined

Comment: @EvanKim, yes that is the reason it doesn't hold for $L=0$.

Comment: Would this hold if $0 < L < 1$?

Comment: Yes it will, do you see any argument that doesn't hold in that case, @EvanKim??

Comment: I don't immediately see any argument that holds if L is a positive number.

Comment: @EvanKim, every argument holds for every positive $L$!!

Comment: Is it accurate to say that we take the smaller $\delta$ because we want the smaller $\delta$-neighborhood? Does a smaller $\delta$-neighborhood imply that a function takes less $x$ values to converge to a certain number?

Comment: @EvanKim, it doesn't say anything about the rate of convergence, the point is that we want to show that the limit of $f(x)g(x)$ is $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $c$, and for that we wish to show that there exists such a $\delta$, the smaller one will do the job, hence we are taking that. The larger one may also do, but we don't know that.